# Sketchup Ruby, add texture to Face

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I am using this, to add draw a box, then coloring the box.

```
l=96
w=60
h=60
clr='Gray'
ent = Sketchup.active_model.entities

#---------Clear All
Sketchup.active_model.entities.clear!       
#----------------
model = Sketchup.active_model

model.start_operation "Create Box"
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------      

entities = model.active_entities
group = entities.add_group
entities = group.entities
group.name = "Box"
@pt0 = [0, 0, 0]
@pt1 = [0, l*12, 0]
@pt2 = [w*12.0, l*12, 0]
@pt3 = [w*12, 0, 0]

newface = entities.add_face(@pt0, @pt1, @pt2, @pt3)
newface.material = Sketchup::Color.new clr
newface.reverse!
newface.pushpull h*12
```

I would also like to add a texture but can't find how to do that.

Like "Metal Corrugated Shiny" but have not been able to find out how to do that.

Does anybody know how to add the texture with ruby?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element that you want is `Texture`.  This is the class object that exposes information about image textures (such as width and height, average color, etc.).

The easiest way to set a texture is directly on the material.

```
newface.material = Sketchup::Color.new clr
newface.material.texture = "C:\\MyMaterialDirectory\\MyMaterial.jpg"
```

Obviously the file will need to be a valid image and in the appropriate directory.

https://ruby.sketchup.com/Sketchup/Texture.html

Comment: Thanks, when I go to the materials folder, it's empty

Comment: If you are looking for the default location where SketchUp stores it's built in materials, that's C:\Users\All Users\SketchUp\SketchUp 2017\SketchUp\Materials (or whatever your version of SketchUp that you are using).  Note, though, that the materials are stored in .skm format which is actually just a zip file.

Comment: Your material texture doesn't have to come from there though.  You can use any image file on your drive